# PHP to Mysql Line break Question

Tags: php, mysql, line-breaks

I am having hard time getting a form submitted textarea where people put in line breaks when they hit enter on their address..For example.

```
<textarea name="address"></textarea>
```

I am using this to get the post

```
$address = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['address']));
```

They are entering `123 test <return>city,state`.

Then after they submit, in the mysql database the address is showing `123 testnrcity state`

So how can I handle this?

Thanks!

Comment: php's `nl2br()` method ?

Comment: How do you insert the `$address` to your `INSERT` query? What is the field type?

Comment: Post the code that stores `$address` in the database. There's smell in that code. Do you use `stripslashes` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Can't tell you much on the mysql part because I am using a WP function add_user_meta($id,'string',$address);

Comment: Are you sure that the WP function doesn't already call `mysql_real_escape_string`? You might be escaping twice...

Comment: @Jakob - I don't know...I didn't assume it did so I just put in the best practice to do so but it is possible the WP function already does this...

Comment: @Rick: it is highly probable that WP takes care of chores such as escaping the data. Do not escape the data yourself.

Comment: I'd expect you see `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`, a blank space, an empty string or even a real line feed but... `nr`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to resolve this the way I wanted to and just settled with using str_replace() to replace all "\r\n" stuff with a space...

Answer (score 1):

Use nl2br?

```
$address = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(nl2br($_POST['address'])));
```

HTH :)

Comment: Yeah I tried that already and it comes back 123 testing lane<br />rnsecond line

Comment: Don't store HTML-escaped text in the database. The place of HTML-escaping is in the output layer. (What if you want to send it to NON-html a output?) HTML entities "do not look" good in CSV or JSON outputs.

Comment: @vbence - so what do I do?  can you give an example?

Comment: I still don't get where the nr is coming from. :S

Comment: @Rick try str_ireplace to change such things to what U need it to be

Comment: This does not explain why he's getting a literal "nr" string.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked what's in your database field? Just show the database contents with phpMyAdmin or a similar tool. The line break can either be a line break character or two characters: `\n`. If it's the latter, then your input probably was escaped twice. Or is it just "n". Then there is probably another escaping somewhere along the way. Do you use a database abstraction layer? Maybe it escapes the values too.